# How to get Client Application Name in Mule API proxy custom policy?

Tags: mule4, anypoint-api-manager

I am developing a custom policy to apply to a Mule gateway API proxy.

I need to capture the client application name and log it. I have access to the client ID from the request header and a client-id-enforcement policy is already applied to the proxy.

The only way I can think of getting the client app name is to use the platform API to retrieve the client applications for the proxy and filter them by client ID. Is there an easy way to get the client application name using the client ID?

Comment: Do you want to log the application name in the policy or in the application? Why do you need to log it?

Comment: I need to log it via the policy (which ultimately logs in the application logs). It's an organization analytics requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's as easy as

```
#[authentication.properties.clientName]
```

Source: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-get-the-client-application-name-in-a-flow-based-on-the-client-id-and-client-secret